# STM32f407VEt6 + ethernet + uip + dp83848 how can I do ping project?

Tags: ping, ethernet, keil, stm32f4discovery, stm32cubemx

Good day!

I am writing a project for stm32f407vet6, the essence is simple - exchange over ethernet between the board and the upper level.
I tried to use the LWIP stack, but the board does not start with it the first time and the ping does not pass every time....

Therefore, I want to try to connect a simpler uip stack, but I don't know how to do it correctly, what steps to take.
There are fewer guides on the Internet about this than for lwip, and for dp83848 physics - not at all.
Maybe someone has a ready-made project, the simplest, or someone knows the specific steps?
I will be glad of any hints, sources.

If for more specific questions - how is the sending of data on eth at the lowest level? To make the question more clear:
For other physics, in its driver there is a function `enc28j60_send_packet((uint8_t *) uip_buf, uip_lan);`
And for my dp83848 there is no such function.
How to properly implement sending eth frames with it? How to initialize correctly?

I tried to build the project in CubeMX, connected ethernet and TIM6 there. Then I connected the uip library to Keil. In main, I wrote the following code:

````
        int main(void)
        {
            uip_ip4addr_t addrm;
            uip_ip4addr_t addrt;
            struct uip_udp_conn *c;
            uip_ipaddr(&addrt, 192,168,1,1);
            uip_ipaddr(&addrm, 1192,168,1,123);
            
            HAL_Init();

            SystemClock_Config();

            MX_GPIO_Init();
            MX_ETH_Init();
            MX_TIM6_Init();
            hello_world_init();
            c = uip_udp_new(&addrt, HTONS(12345));
            uip_connect(&addrt, HTONS(12345));
            HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT   (&htim6);
         
            while (1)
            {
                
                uip_udp_conn = c;
                uip_appdata  = &my_udp_buf;
                uip_udp_packet_send(c, uip_appdata, strlen(uip_appdata) );//Im trying it first
                uip_send(uip_appdata, my_udp_buf_len);//then it
                uip_udp_packet_send(c,uip_appdata, 8 );//then it
                uip_udp_packet_sendto(c,uip_appdata, 8 , &addrm, 12345 );//and it last
                     
            }}

        ```
        void
        uip_udp_packet_sendto(struct uip_udp_conn *c, const void *data, int len,
                            const uip_ipaddr_t *toaddr, uint16_t toport)
        {
            uip_ipaddr_t curaddr;
            uint16_t curport;

            if(toaddr != NULL) {
                /* Save current IP addr/port. */
                uip_ipaddr_copy(&curaddr, &c->ripaddr);
                curport = c->rport;

                /* Load new IP addr/port */
                uip_ipaddr_copy(&c->ripaddr, toaddr);
                c->rport = toport;

                uip_udp_packet_send(c, data, len);

                /* Restore old IP addr/port */
                uip_ipaddr_copy(&c->ripaddr, &curaddr);
                c->rport = curport;
            }
        }
            void
            uip_udp_packet_send(struct uip_udp_conn *c, const void *data, int len)
            { 
             if(data != NULL && len <= (UIP_BUFSIZE - (UIP_LLH_LEN + UIP_IPUDPH_LEN))) {
                uip_udp_conn = c;
                uip_len = len;
                memmove(&uip_buf[UIP_LLH_LEN + UIP_IPUDPH_LEN], data, len);
                uip_process(UIP_UDP_SEND_CONN);


        }}
````